# How to dynamically change ip address of client in c#?

Tags: c#, ip, client

In my client-server winform app,want to change ip address of client each time i run it.
A text box should take ip address of my client and then connect to server using local ip which is on same computer.

**Client code:**

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
        NetworkStream serverStream;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public void ConnectToServer()
        {
            string server_localip = GetLocalIP();
            clientSocket.Connect(server_localip, 8888);

        }

        public void SendData(string dataTosend)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataTosend))
                return;
            NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            byte[] outStream = new byte[33];
            outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataTosend);
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();


        }

        public void CloseConnection()
        {
            clientSocket.Close();
        }
        public string ReceiveData()
        {
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            serverStream.ReadTimeout = 100;
            //the loop should continue until no dataavailable to read and message string is filled.
            //if data is not available and message is empty then the loop should continue, until
            //data is available and message is filled.
            while (true)
            {
                if (serverStream.DataAvailable)
                {
                    int read = serverStream.ReadByte();
                    if (read > 0)
                        message.Append((char)read);
                    else
                        break;
                }
                else if (message.ToString().Length > 0)
                    break;
            }
            return message.ToString();
        }
        public string GetLocalIP()
        {
            IPHostEntry host;
            host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            return "127.0.0.1";
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConnectToServer();
            btnConnect.Text = "Connected";
        }

        private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtPrivateId.Text, @"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"))
            //{
            //    lblError.Text ="Please type a valid IMPI.";
            //}
            //if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtPublicId.Text, "[^0-9]"))
            //{
            //    lblError.Text = lblError.Text + "\nPlease type a valid IMPU.";
            //}
            //else
            //{
            lblError.Text = "";


            string data = txtPrivateId.Text + ";" + txtPublicId.Text;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                SendData(data);
            }

            string rec = null;
            rec = ReceiveData();
            txtReceive.Text = rec;
        }
    }
```

Any guidance would be appreciated..

Comment: You can only do this if you can guarantee your app will be running as an Administrator with elevated permissions.

Comment: yes,i will run it on my computer(im administrator).I'm doing it for testing purpose that how my server will react to the requests coming from various clients(having different IPs).

Answer (score 0):

you can use netsh to change your ip address:

```
netsh interface ip set address [adapter name] static [ip address] [subnet mask] [gateway] [interface metric]
```

try the code below:

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", "interface ip set address \"Local Area Connection\" static 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1");
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();
```

and remember that your application should be running in elevated permissions.
"Local Area Connection" should match your adapter name
for more information about the netsh command line switches visit the Microsoft knowledge base article below:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/242468

Comment: first make sure you typed the adapter name correctly. also you can test the netsh command from your command line prompt